# how do you split a mediawiki xml dump?

Tags: xml, mediawiki, dump

how do you split a mediawiki xml dump? i cannot find out how to do this, as wish to have 5mb max files as import wont work unless small files, and 45mb is too big

Answer (score -1):

there are a number of xml splitter utilities, some OS, some commercial. Some are command-line, others GUI. Search for "split large xml"

Whatever you use, make sure it uses an XML parser, like the ones in Java or .NET, because if the XML is not properly formed, string parsing can really mess you up.

Comment: that does not help me as you never gave links to them, whats easiest to use and understand

Comment: anyone have links?